# Wordpress Category Template with Offset - Featured on every page

Tags: wordpress, post, wordpress-featured-image

I'm trying to make a category template in which, first post is displayed with full text + big thumbnail (as featured) and then posts with titles only + a smaller thumbnail.

I've managed (with help) to do this with two queries, but first post remains the same on each page, won't change, as also, the loop won't adopt the offset of first page into other pages too.

Code is here:

```
<?php $cat_link = get_category_link( $cat_id );
      $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id);
      $cat_id = 22; ?>

<?php $latest_cat_post = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'category__in' => array($cat_id)));
      if( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : while( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : $latest_cat_post->the_post(); ?>

      <div class="catrecent">
           <div class="recenttitle">
           <h2 class="catidtxt"> <a href="<?php echo ($cat_link); ?>" title="<?php echo ($cat_name); ?>"><?php echo ($cat_name); ?></a></h2>
           <h2 class="recentposttitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>       
      </div>
           <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                 <div class="recentpostwrap">
                 <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbcatbig' ); ?>
                 <?php the_content_limit(588,""); ?>
                 <div class="readrecent">
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e("more", "mm"); ?></a>
                 </div>
                 </div>
           <?php } else { ?>
                 <div class="holder no-thumb-big">                                                                               
                 <?php the_content_limit(798,""); ?>
                 <div class="more">
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e("more", "mm"); ?></a>
                 </div>
                 </div>
           <?php } ?>

           <?php endwhile; else: ?><?php endif; ?><?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
     </div>





<ul class="catlist-recent">
    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $ppp = 7;
    $offset = 1;
    $cat_id = '22,27,29';

    //Manually determine page query offset (offset + current page (minus one) x posts per page)
    $page_offset = $offset + ( ($paged - 1) * $ppp );

    $query = new wp_query(array(
        'offset'         => $page_offset,
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'cat'            => $cat_id,
        'paged'          => $paged
    ));

    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <li class="catlist-recentpost">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbcatsmall' ); ?></a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a>
                <div class="catlist-recentposttxt">  <?php the_content_limit(300, ''); ?></div>
    </li>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?><?php endif; ?>
</ul>

<div class="cat-pagenate">
<?php
// pagination
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links(array(
    'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) )    ),
    'total'   => ceil(($query->found_posts - $offset) / $ppp),
    'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
));
wp_reset_query();
?>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query = new wp_query(array(
    'offset' => $page_offset,
    'number' => $ppp,
    'cat' => $cat_id,
    'page' => $paged
));
```

Note the change from "paged" to "page"